# Deploy vue js with symlink on vps always error npm build

Tags: vue.js, npm, deployment, build, npm-build

I've just deployed my Vue project into my Cpanel using ssh. Let's say, I clone the repo to `/var/www/` it will generate the repo right, so it will generate the `repo-generated` folder in `/var/www/`.

So we call it, `/var/www/repo-generated`. And then I get into this folder and start to do an act `npm install` and it has no problem, and then for the servers can read my sites I create the symlink from the `root folder` to my `repo folder`, so I do a command

```
ln -s /var/www/repo-generated/dist/ /var/www/html
```

and its done, the symlink already created.
and for the generated my projects,
i do a command,

```
npm run build
```

and it will generate the `dist` folder on `repo-generated folder` right

but when I do that command, it has an errors.

```
[root@backend-mpp dh-payroll-frontend]# npm run build

> payroll@0.1.0 build /var/www/dh-payroll-frontend
> vue-cli-service build


⠸  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                          10:44:58 PM

 error

ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/www/dh-payroll-frontend/public/dist'

 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! payroll@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the payroll@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-24T14_44_58_346Z-debug.log
```

I using vue.js version 2.

Please help.

Can anyone help me?
Please....

Thank you before everyone ^_^